# Using Insert Hyperlink Dialog to add a link to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I'm writing a small macro to add an entry to my list of calibrated tools. I want to use the insert hyperlink dialog so the user can pick a file and then the macro will add a link to that file in a cell. Here's what I've tried:

[image]

```
If Link = True Then
    Range("H4") = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show
End If
```

But the result is the word "TRUE" blue and underlined, but if I click it it doesn't do anything

[image]

I imagine this is some kind of syntax issue, but I'm having troubling looking it up, most results don't have to do with the dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Hyperlink button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001435/create-hyperlink-button)

Comment: If you want more control then you can use `Application.GetOpenFilename` to get the user's file selection, and add the hyperlink using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Williams for the solve. Here's my solution

```
If Link = True Then
    Range("H4").Select
    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show Then
    End If
End If
```

Very strange syntax for using a dialog box, but it works.

Comment: Tangential, but relevant: from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.dialog): "The only useful thing that you can do with a Dialog object is to use it with the Show method to display the corresponding dialog box."