# How to add a popup to add a hyperlink to a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, web, hyperlink, insert, datasheet

I am new to Excel. I have a data sheet, and a lot of users have to enter their data in the sheet. I have a column with the header - 'linkToData'. Whenever a user clicks on a cell, there has to be a popup, which asks for the 'link text', and 'URL', so the user can enter it easily, than using 'Insert --> Link --> Insert Link'. How do I do this customization? Can you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: On my Excel at least, there is a "Link ..." menu item on the right-click menu, which might speed things up enough for your use case. This answer may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404123/using-insert-hyperlink-dialog-to-add-a-link-to-a-cell

Answer (score 1):

If the existing right-click menu item "Link" is not sufficient, then you can try intercepting the SelectionChange() event for the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nCol As Integer
    nCol = Target.Column
    
    If Target.Row > 1 And Cells(1, nCol) = "linkToData" Then
        If Target.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then
            Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertHyperlink).Show
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Put this code in the VBA module for your sheet (eg "Sheet1(Sheet1)").

If the top cell in the column is "linkToData", and there isn't already a Hyperlink in the cell, then show the Insert Link dialog. You could write you own input form, but this dialog does what you need.